# How to add multiple mail attachment in smtp using Mule ESB

Tags: java, email, smtp, mule, mule-studio

I am trying to find out is there a way to add multiple mail attachment in smtp using Mule ESB.I know we can add attachment in Mule message, but I want a way by which we can add multiple attachment in Mule message before the message goes to the outbound smtp endpoint.
Is there a way by writing Java code for multiple attachment ?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `<set-attachment attachmentName="" value="" contentType="" />` element repeatedly to add several attachments to your Mule message. They should be automatically transformed into MIME attachments in the outbound email message.

Comment: Thanks David  ... I have tried your process... I have set a .zip file setting the content type as "application/zip" and a .pdf file keeping the content type as "application/pdf".... I received the message with the attachment but the attachment was corrupted and damaged .... 

If I don't set the content type and leave it blank then Mule throws and exception and unable to process...

Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

So, as per David's suggestion the working solution is :-

```
<set-attachment value="#[message.payload]" contentType="application/zip" attachmentName="#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']]" doc:name="Attachment" />
```

where `#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']]` contains the file name from file inbound