# Sending email with multiple attachment is not working in mule ESB using set-attachment

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

```
<flow name="SendmailFlow" >
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="${sendmail.path}" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <!--  http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        host="${sendmail.host}" port="${sendmail.port}" path="${sendmail.path}" doc:name="HTTP" /-->

    <logger message="logging #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />

    <json:json-to-object-transformer
        returnClass="com.rsa.esbcommons.mailsender.MailData" doc:name="JSON to Object" />

    <foreach collection="#[payload.getAttachments()]" doc:name="For Each Attachment in MailData">           
        <set-attachment attachmentName="#[payload.getFilename()]" value="#[payload.getBase64AttachmentContent()]"
            contentType="#[payload.getContentType()]" doc:name="Create Attachment" />
    </foreach>  

    <smtp:outbound-endpoint user="${smtp.user}" password="${smtp.password}" host="${smtp.host}" from="${smtp.from}" responseTimeout="10000"
        doc:name="SMTP" mimeType="text/html" transformer-refs="MailDataToEmailTransformer StringToEmail" />
    <custom-transformer class="com.rsa.esbcommons.mailsender.MailResponseMessageTransformer" doc:name="MailResponseTransformer"/>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer sourceClass="com.rsa.esbcommons.mailsender.BaseResponse" doc:name="Sendmail response to JSON"/>

</flow>
```

Here the issue is attachment fails when set-attachment is used in foreach loop which is given above.  This is for sending multiple attachment with email.   Can we use set-attachment in foreach loop?Please  help thanks in advance

Comment: What is the payload before going into the foreach? Does it really contain attachments at that point so as to use that as the collection for foreach?

Comment: Foreach loop contains list of MailAttachment objects.payload is an object of type MailAttachment pojo having the folllowing fields    
   filename;
   contentType;
   base64AttachmentContent;
Values are set properly but attachment fails.

Comment: If the payload is already a list then you shouldn't add the collection attribute. Try deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

This post is old but I expose my solution for those who have the same problem.

The problem here is after foreach sentence, mule message is recovering his original state (empty outboundAttachments). You must create temporary flow var, and overwrite it in each iteration with current message.outboundAttachments. Finally, outside for each scope, you must set message.outboundAttachments copying from temporary var. Here the code you should try.

```
<flow name="SendmailFlow" >
<http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="${sendmail.path}" doc:name="HTTP"/>

    <json:json-to-object-transformer
        returnClass="com.rsa.esbcommons.mailsender.MailData" doc:name="JSON to Object" />

    <set-variable variableName="attaches" value="#[new java.util.HashMap()]" />

    <foreach collection="#[payload.getAttachments()]" doc:name="For Each Attachment in MailData">           
        <set-attachment attachmentName="#[payload.getFilename()]" value="#[payload.getBase64AttachmentContent()]"
            contentType="#[payload.getContentType()]" doc:name="Create Attachment" />

        <expression-component><![CDATA[java.util.Set keys = message.outboundAttachments.keySet();
        for(Object key:keys){flowVars.attaches.put(key, message.outboundAttachments.get(key));
        }]]>
        </expression-component>
    </foreach>

    <expression-component>
    <![CDATA[
    message.outboundAttachments.putAll(flowVars.attaches);
    ]]>
    </expression-component>

<smtp:outbound-endpoint user="${smtp.user}" password="${smtp.password}" host="${smtp.host}" from="${smtp.from}" responseTimeout="10000"
        doc:name="SMTP" mimeType="text/html" transformer-refs="MailDataToEmailTransformer StringToEmail" />
    <custom-transformer class="com.rsa.esbcommons.mailsender.MailResponseMessageTransformer" doc:name="MailResponseTransformer"/>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer sourceClass="com.rsa.esbcommons.mailsender.BaseResponse" doc:name="Sendmail response to JSON"/>

</flow>`
```

And i'm not sure if you should delete string to email transformer ref. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use set-attachment in foreach component. no issue in that. The problem you got is related to something else. Try to put debug and see whats happening. better check your MEL expressions whether those returning values properly(keep logger to print values). check the below links for further assistance

[How to add multiple mail attachment in smtp using Mule ESB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327131/how-to-add-multiple-mail-attachment-in-smtp-using-mule-esb)

https://dzone.com/articles/handling-file-attachments

Comment: <foreach collection="#[payload.getAttachments()]" doc:name="For Each Attachment in MailData">           
        <set-attachment attachmentName="#[payload.getFilename()]" value="#[payload.getBase64AttachmentContent()]"
            contentType="#[payload.getContentType()]" doc:name="Create Attachment" />
    </foreach> 

This part is not working.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is very similar to J.Antonio Rubio's, but I simplified the expression inside the `foreach` just a little:

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer
    returnClass="com.rsa.esbcommons.mailsender.MailData" doc:name="JSON to Object" />

<set-variable variableName="attaches" value="#[new java.util.HashMap()]" />

<foreach collection="#[payload.getAttachments()]" doc:name="For Each Attachment in MailData">           
    <set-attachment attachmentName="#[payload.getFilename()]" value="#[payload.getBase64AttachmentContent()]"
        contentType="#[payload.getContentType()]" doc:name="Create Attachment" />

    <expression-component><![CDATA[flowVars.attaches.putAll(message.outboundAttachments);]]>
    </expression-component>
</foreach>

<expression-component>
<![CDATA[
message.outboundAttachments.putAll(flowVars.attaches);
]]>
</expression-component>
```